# Android Webview not occupying full screen when opened via phonegap childBrowser plugin

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova, childbrowser

My Phonegap based app shows some URLs in childBrowser webview, but the child view opens as a pop up and does not occupies the full screen.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Here is my layout.xml for the sub view which shows user entered URLs

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >



    <ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/backButton"

        android:layout_width="50dp"

        android:layout_height="28dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:src="@drawable/backbutton"

        android:contentDescription="@string/back_label" />



    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:clickable="false"

        android:textColor="#fff"

        android:text="@string/back_label" />

</FrameLayout>



<TextView

    android:id="@+id/titleBar"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="44dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:textIsSelectable="false"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:text="@string/title"

    android:textSize="16sp"

    android:textStyle="bold" />



<WebView

    android:id="@+id/webView"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />



<TextView

    android:id="@+id/statusBar"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="44dp"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"

    android:textIsSelectable="false"

    android:textSize="16sp"

    android:paddingLeft="8dp"

    android:textStyle="bold" />
```